# Catch angular wildcard route if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular project, i'm resolving most of the routes from a wildcard

```
function getTemplateUrl (route) {
  return '/views/' + route.page + '.html';
}
.when('/:page', { templateUrl : getTemplateUrl })
.when('/:page/:edit', { templateUrl : getTemplateUrl })
.otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'});
```

the only issue, is that when the route doesn't exist, it will still try to load the page, not the `otherwise` function and loads the page over and over again, thus creating an infinite loop.

Is there any way I can check if the route exists?

Comment: You didn't add route for `dashboard` yet.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to redirect all other pages to `dashboard`, you should specify dashboard route before `otherwise`

```
function getTemplateUrl (route) {
  return '/views/' + route.page + '.html';
}
.when('/:page', { templateUrl : getTemplateUrl })
.when('/:page/:edit', { templateUrl : getTemplateUrl })
.when('/dashboard', { templateUrl : getTemplateUrl })
//add dashboard route before otherwise
.otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'});
```

Comment: but `:page` will be what matches `/dashboard`, so it will never get to that hardcoded dashboard route, just like it won't get to the otherwise.